# aiohttp ConnectionError: Cannot send requests while disconnected

Tags: python, aiohttp

I'm using aiohttp as server and telethon client for sending messages.

Running this edited code from telegrammodule.py is working fine:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import asyncio

api_id = censored
api_hash = "censored"
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

async def sendMessageToUser(user, message):
        await client.send_message(user, message)

def sendMessage(user, message):
        with client:
                client.loop.run_until_complete(sendMessageToUser(user, message))


sendMessage("censored", "Hello")
```

This is the error I get when I try to call the function `sendMessage()` from server.py:

```
======== Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000 ========
(Press CTRL+C to quit)
Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 418, in start
    resp = await task
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/aiohttp/web_app.py", line 458, in _handle
    resp = await handler(request)
  File "server.py", line 9, in send
    response = await sendMessage(user, message)
  File "/home/user/telegram_user_bot/telegrammodule.py", line 13, in sendMessage
    client.loop.run_until_complete(sendMessageToUser(user, message))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 571, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 526, in run_forever
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<sendMessageToUser() done, defined at /home/user/telegram_user_bot/telegrammodule.py:8> exception=ConnectionError('Cannot send requests while disconnected')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/telegram_user_bot/telegrammodule.py", line 9, in sendMessageToUser
    await client.send_message(user, message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/telethon/client/messages.py", line 752, in send_message
    result = await self(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 53, in __call__
    future = self._sender.send(request, ordered=ordered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/telethon/network/mtprotosender.py", line 170, in send
    raise ConnectionError('Cannot send requests while disconnected')
ConnectionError: Cannot send requests while disconnected
```

Here's the code from server.py:

```
from telegrammodule import sendMessage
from aiohttp import web
import asyncio

async def send(request):
        data = await request.post()
        user = data['user']
        message = data['message']
        response = await sendMessage(user, message)

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_post("/send", send)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        web.run_app(app, port=5000)
```

And here from telegrammodule.py:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import asyncio

api_id = censored
api_hash = "censored"
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

async def sendMessageToUser(user, message):
        await client.send_message(user, message)

async def sendMessage(user, message):
        async with client:
                client.loop.run_until_complete(sendMessageToUser(user, message))
```

I don't know how to solve the problem. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If a loop is already running, you can't start it one more time. Use [`create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task), to add a task to a running loop.

For your case

```
client.loop.create_task(sendMessageToUser(user, message))
```

would be a fix, I guess.

Also, if the `client.loop` is in another thread, you might use [`run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe):

```
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(sendMessageToUser(user, message), client.loop)
```

And one more important thing - if `client.loop` is the loop you're currently in, you can await `sendMessageToUser(user, message)` until message is sent.